# Avoid \bigskips

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
  enhanced,
  boxrule=2mm,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\centering,
  title=#2,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{\LARGE Heading Text}

  \lipsum[1]

  \bigskip

  \lipsum[2]

  \bigskip

  \lipsum[3]

\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

I want to avoid inserting the `\bigskip`s between paragraphs but want to maintain the exact same spacing between paragraphs. How do I achieve that? I tried `\setlength{\parskip}{3em}` in the preamble. But that did not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `before upper` key. If you use `before upper=\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}`, then this should give you the desired effect.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
  enhanced,
  boxrule=2mm,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\centering,
  before upper=\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount},
  title=#2,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{\LARGE Heading Text}

  \lipsum[1]

  \lipsum[2]

  \lipsum[3]

\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Obviously one can set the `\parindent` in the analogous way, if needed.

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly